# how to handle file input from an HTML form using py-script?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am using `pyscript` implement Python3 code into HTML files. I am currently trying to have a user submit a form and then I will run an algorithm on the data that is inside the form, ideally a .txt file.

Here is my table

```html
<div class="container border big" style="display: block" id="formDiv">
  <iframe name="k" style="display: none"></iframe>

  <form target="k">
    <label for="numberOfTables">Number of Tables</label>

    <input
      type="number"
      class="form-control"
      id="numberOfTables"
      aria-describedby="numberOfTables"
      placeholder="Number of Tables as an integer"
    />

    <label for="studentList">
      List of Students with name, sex, group number (example file <a href="example.txt" style="color: blue">here</a>)
    </label>

    <input
      type="file"
      class="form-control"
      id="studentList"
      aria-describedby="studentList"
      placeholder="Student list as a .txt file"
    />

    <br />

    <div id="fileInput"></div>

    <input
      type="submit"
      id="button"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      py-click="test()"
      value="Display Tables"
    />
  </form>
</div>
```

I am able to access "numberOfTables" once the form is submitted through the following code:

```html
<py-script>
def test():
    number = Element("numberOfTables").value
</py-script>
```

But how would I access the information in the file? If I try to just do `Element(studentList).value`, then i get the string `C:\fakepath\filename.txt`.